# get_stylesheet_directory not working properly

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am having an issue with loading some javascript in a child theme I am creating for one of my themes.

Essentially I do:

```
get_stylesheet_directory() . '/path/to/javascript.js'
```

which is what your suppose to do, But , as per the documentation, I am getting:

```
mysite.com/dev/home/path/to/wordpress/path/to/theme/path/to/js.js
```

which is causing it to not find the required file. because home is at the root of the site.

any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get_stylesheet_directory() returns a server path. I'm pretty sure you want:

```
get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');
```

That will return a URL of your stylesheet directory in relation to your Wordpress Installation so you can load external assets like Javascript files that reside in your theme.

Comment: Note: what I really wanted, after more reading was get_stylesheet_directory_uri();

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/path/to/javascript.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to enqueue scripts and styles the WordPress way.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Put this in `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue' );
function enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/theme.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/theme.js' );
}
```